# How to dismiss input type color popup in html?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How to dismiss the `<input type="color" />` popup dialog from JavaScript?. I want to dismiss the dialog on `onBlur` event.

Comment: why not just override the onblur event ?

Comment: What should be written inside onblur event handler function?

Comment: added an answer with code

Comment: note that I use jquery.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question.

When you click the input a window pops out and will not close until you click "ok" or "x".

You want to close this window onblur. 

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, i want to close that color chooser onblur.

Comment: Ok sorry for the confusion :).  When you say onblur do you mean the onblur event of the input tag or when you click outside the color chooser? those are two different things

Comment: I believe your question is the latter.  The onblur event will fire almost immediately after you click the input.  This is because your browser will have focus on the color picker, thus blurred away from the input. If you were to close the color picker on blur then it would open and close almost instantly.  Since I don't have access to what the html5 input does in the background, and haven't found documentation on it, I would suggest using a javascript color picker to give you more control over it.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with HTML5 color picker since it's implementation is browser/os dependand. What you could do is to use jQuery plugin like https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/ instead